# the correct way to map values into a df (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

hey guys I have a df which i split in terms of gender and I try and map values to a column based on a dictionary as per below

```
males = speed_dating.loc[speed_dating['gender'] == 0]
females = speed_dating.loc[speed_dating['gender'] == 1]


race_dictionary = {1.0: "Black", 2.0: "European", 3.0:"Hispanic", 4.0: "Asian", 5.0:"Native American", 6.0:"Other"}


males['race'] = males['race'].map(race_dictionary)
```

but what happens when I do this is

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  males['race'] = males['race'].map(race_dictionary)
```

which I do not understand becuase I am trying to set values on a dataframe I established through the first line?

can someone explain this?

Comment: The warning is letting you know that `males` is a copy of a slice of `speed_dating`.  If that is fine, and you want `males` to be it's own data-frame, then ignore the warning.

Comment: Adding on to @juanpa.arrivillaga's answer, you can turn this warning off with `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None` if you don't want to see this warning again.

Comment: Or, you can `map` onto your *original* dataframe, then seperate out males and females.